# How to include css in mulitple jsps?

Tags: css, jsp, include

i have several CSS styles i would need to include in the JSP page, however, i have multiple JSP where i include in a main JSP. I can't modify the main JSP, but only be able to put them into the included JSPs.

May i know if i may have a  tag in each JSP so that i may put my page level CSS?

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .oneOffcosts_totalDescription{
            color: #006685;
            margin-left:35px;
            border:1px solid #dedede;
            width:300px;
            float:left;
            display:inline;
        }

        .oneOffcosts_totalCost{
            font-weight:bold;
            border:1px solid #dedede;
            width:100px;
            float:left;
            display:inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want to add some file content (css) for few jsp's. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, to each JSP that is included in a main JSP. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a ***include-prelude*** in the ***jsp-property-group*** in ***web.xml*** for the jsps which you want the content to be added.

```
<jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
  <url-pattern>/included/a.jsp</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/included/b.jsp</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/included/*.jsp</url-pattern>
  <include-prelude>
    /WEB-INF/somecss.css
  </include-prelude>
  <include-coda>

  </include-coda>
</jsp-property-group>
```

Comment: Will this solution crash with if i am using a Struts framework?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new file , say mainWithCss.jsp which includes your main.jsp along with style-info or links to your CSS-files. Include this instead of for main.jsp.

If you can't access the HEAD element (if it in your un-editable main.jsp) I would suggest linking to external CSS files instead.