# Checking if a user is already logged in or the session is started in jsp

Tags: jsp

I am trying to design a simple login system using jsp. In the login page, the user inputs his username and password which on verification gets executed as

---

```
if username and password combination exists, then
{

     HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

     if (session == null) {
          // Session not created yet. So we do it now.
           session = request.getSession();
           session.setAttribute("id",idvariable );
           response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
          // I redirect them to their profile home pages
    } 

    else {
        // Session is already created.
         response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
       // So i again redirect them to their home page
    }
 }
```

---

Now in the  "home.jsp" how do i check if the session has already been created ??

---

**I would need to check if the session has already been started at every page in the profile. So i would like to create some sort of function that i could call in at the top of every jsp page **

---

What should i do ??

Answer (score 1):

Don't add/write Java code in `Jsp`. You should have to design a `filter` to authenticate a user.

Edit:

Take a look at tutorial -  [info (servlet-filters)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)

Comment: I know i should java code in jsp, however can u please tell me what is the method if i try to do so..

Comment: Don't you already have the code in your question? You can put that in a filter and then each request will check the session. No need to add anything to your JSP. +1

Answer (score 1):

first create a class like this.. to set the user bean attributes
this example assume one user for simplicity

```
public class Users implements Serializable {
    private String user;

 public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

then on login check like this

```
   String userName = request.getRequest().getParameter("txtid");
   String password = request.getRequest().getParameter("txtPassword");

Vector params = new Vector();

        params.add(null);//return result from procedure
        params.add(Name);
        params.add(password);


 Users mainUser = new Users ();
 Vector tempResults = callingDaoProcedure.executeGetPasswordogin(params);//finds the password in DB

if (!tempResults.isEmpty()) {

                    mainUser = (MainUsers) tempResults.get(0);
 if (mainUser.getPassword().trim().equals(password.trim())) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);


         if (request.getSession().getAttribute("userLogin") == null) {
              // Session not created yet. So we do it now.
               session = request.getSession();
               requestgetRequest().setAttribute("status", "NO_ERRORS");
               request.getSession().setAttribute("userLogin", mainUser);
               response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
              // I redirect them to their profile home pages
        } 

        else {
            // Session is already created.
             response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
           // So i again redirect them to their home page
        }
}
else
{
              request.getRequest().setAttribute("status", "WRONG_PASSWORD");
              System.out.println("wrong password");
}


}
```

the code above is not error free but since you provided a missing code this is as closeset as i get to your case any way you can access this variable on each jsp like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="${sessionScope['userLogin'].user}">
```

**i hope it helps and most important you learned somthing from it**

Answer (score 1):

Use JSP `Prelude` which adds the jsp to the begining of all jsps. And check if the sesion already exists.

**References:**

- [Example which shows how to add Jsp Prelude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944433/use-a-url-pattern-for-include-file/10945117#10945117)
- [How to include page for all Jsps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327341/how-to-include-css-in-mulitple-jsps/6327586#6327586)