# Redirect a bookmarked page to login page

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, authentication, bookmarks

I've a login page and some pages managed with session after login. If a user bookmarks a page after logging in, and tries to access the same bookmark later, I want that page to be redirected to login page again to enable secure access. How can this be achieved with jsp. Or is there some other way like javascript,etc., I would appreciate any help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be insecure to do on the client side. It would be most easy done with session variables.

Answer (score 0):

IT's hard to say for sure without seeing any code. Essentially what you need to do is check the users session to see if it is still valid and then do the redirect if it is not valid.

you can redirect in JavaScript via

```
window.location = "Redirect Url"
```

You say you are using JSP so check this question, it looks to be what you need to do.

[Checking if a user is already logged in or the session is started in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244580/checking-if-a-user-is-already-logged-in-or-the-session-is-started-in-jsp)

Comment: Can you give me an outline of how it can be achieved with session. I am currently using session variable. but how do i achieve redirection  along with javascript as you have said